# Global Action Error Message - Error: No Lightning Component Quick Actions are available for your organization

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, aura, html5, global-actions

In a dev org, I am trying to create a Global Action to call a Flow via a LWC, but I am receiving the following error messages:

[image: Screenshot of error messages stating "Error: No Lightning Component Quick Actions are available for your organization" and "Error: Field cannot be set for type Lightning Component"]

Here is the code for the component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
   <!-- Add scroll bar to docked composer -->
     <div class="slds-docked-composer">
         <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" />
     </div>
    <!-- Component is initialized -->
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" /> 
 </aura:component>
```

Here's the style code:

```
.THIS .slds-docked-composer {
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

And here's the controller code:

```
({
    init : function(component) {
        // Find the component whose aura:id is "flowData"
        let flow = component.find("flowData");
        // In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow's Unique Name/API Name.THIS
    flow.startFlow("New_Case");
    }
})
```

I am able to create the Action in a sandbox. The only difference is that in the sandbox, I wrote the code in the Dev Console in Salesforce, whereas for this dev org (my personal org used in job interviews, etc.) I used VSCode and deployed to the org from there.

In addtion, I am able to create the Action in the dev org when I leave Standard Label Type as None. However, when I edit the Action to add the Label Type, I still receive the "Error: Field cannot be set for type Lightning Component" message.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional testing, I noticed that--even though I was unable to assign a Standard Label Type to the Action--the Action was still created, along with a mobile/lightning button. I assigned the button to the global publisher layout and tested it, and the button and Flow are both working correctly. It appears there is some issue with assigning a Standard Label Type to a Lightning component, but for my purposes I don't need one.

[image: Screenshot of newly-created global action]

[image: Screenshot of new global action in Global Actions menu]

[image: Screenshot of New Case Flow in docked composer]